# Publish Wizard with Visual Studio doesn't include native binaries of libgit2

Tags: libgit2sharp

I'm trying to publish my application with the publish tool from Visual Studio.
When I build the app, the `NativeBinaries` directory with `libgit2` for x86 and `amd64` is well copied in the build directory bin/Release, so the application run perfectly in my dev environment.

The problem is, with the Publish Wizard to create a ClickOnce Application, the native binaries are not integrated, so I have an error on another computer :

```
System.DllNotFoundException: Impossible de charger la DLL 'git2-e0902fb': Le   module spécifié est introuvable. (Exception de HRESULT : 0x8007007E)
   à LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods.git_libgit2_init()
   à LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods.LibraryLifetimeObject..ctor()
   à LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods..cctor()
```

`LibGit2Sharp.dll.deploy` is correctly copied in the Application Files directory at the end of the publish process.

I tried many solutions I found, like to create a link with the `.dll` files or using a post or pre-build event.

IDE : Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows Desktop.

`LibGit2Sharp.0.21.0.176` is installed with `NuGet`.

Comment: Hmmmm. This doesn't seem like a programming related issue. More like a potential missing feature with regards to the way we interact with the publishing pipeline. Could you please log an entry in the **[issue tracker](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues)**?

Comment: Thank you, I opened a new issue.

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/1126

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the native binary files aren't included in the ClickOnce manifest is that their Build Action is set to None by the LibGit2Sharp.NativeBinaries NuGet package. The Publish Wizard only includes files that are set to Content.

You could link the NativeBinaries folder from the NuGet package into your project and set the Build Action to Content, but you'd need to maintain that manually any time the package updates.

Another option would be to manually add the files to the ClickOnce manifest using the procedure described **[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fehc36e(v=vs.120).aspx)**.

However, the best option is probably to avoid using ClickOnce in the first place. I recommend taking a look at **[Squirrel](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows)** instead.